# Pass through an array as a $ajax parameter MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method in my controller which takes an array as a parameter:

```
public JsonResult AddItemToBasketFlavours(int skuID, string description, long[] qualifiers){}
```

How can I pass through an array of two items to this method from javascript?

**I've tried this:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { skuID: sku, description: productDescription, qualifiers: sweetSKUID,qualifiers:drinkSKUID },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (result) {

    }

});
```

When I step through the code in the controller the qualifiers array has only one item, I need both of them to be present

Comment: where is your array code??

Comment: `qualifiers: [sweetSKUID, drinkSKUID]` perhaps

Comment: @user574632 I have tried this, the qualifiers array is null in the controller if I do it this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the parameter `traditional` to true, and use a js array:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    traditional: true, //<- set this
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { skuID: sku, description: productDescription, qualifiers: [sweetSKUID, drinkSKUID] },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (result) {

    }

});
```

Comment: if we not set it true array will not be posted?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad no, it just changes the serialization method - asp.net expects the traditional method, php, ruby etc expect the new method. So only set it if the end point you are posting to requires it (like the asp.net method in this question)